# Is there a way to close Skyrim without using the task manager?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When the game freeze, I can't access the task manager by using crtl alt delete, because the game screen covers the task manager and I can't click on the task manager. The game screen being in lower resolution than my desktop resolution. Is there a way to shut down skyrim without logging out of Windows?

Comment: Does alt+tab work?

Answer (score 8):

On **Windows 10** it is possible to have multiple desktops, and to move the unresponsive Skyrim window to the other desktop so it's no longer blocking access to Task Manager:

1. Use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to bring up the window switcher.
2. Click New Desktop in the bottom right corner of the screen.
3. Hover over Desktop 1 (at the bottom of the screen) to get the windows back.
4. Drag and drop the unresponsive TESV.exe window onto Desktop 2.
5. Use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cancel the window switcher.

You can now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up Task Manager as normal.

Comment: Does this method work when even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> has no effect?

Comment: @user598527: In my experience, when Skyrim crashes, Ctrl+Alt+Delete *does* work to a point, but once you click "Task Manager", it goes wrong because the TESV.exe window obstinately covers the Task Manager window.

Answer (score 5):

Use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run prompt and type `taskkill /IM TESV.exe /F`<kbd>Enter</kbd> to kill off the Skyrim process.

Comment: I assume you have to type blindly?

Comment: If you can't see it (which is probably the case), yes.

Answer (score 5):

Enable `always on top` in task manager options.

Comment: alt+o, alt+a to enable it blindly, at least on windows 10.

Comment: @3ventic: alt + o + a actually.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. This should close the active window (no matter if the program in that window has crashed).

Answer (score 1):

ctrl + tab, then just click the x
it works all the time for me, when alt f4 doesnt work